# Install Aurora PostgresSql using cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Unable to create aurora postgresSql database using cloudformat yaml template.
Please help me on this.

Comment: Please add more info about your problem: error message, related part of YAML template etc

Comment: For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

From [AWS::RDS::DBCluster - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbcluster.html):

> The following example creates an Amazon Aurora PostgreSQL DB cluster that exports logs to Amazon CloudWatch Logs. For more information about exporting Aurora DB cluster logs to Amazon CloudWatch Logs.

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: >-
  AWS CloudFormation Sample Template for sending Aurora DB cluster logs to
  CloudWatch Logs: Sample template showing how to create an Aurora PostgreSQL DB
  cluster that exports logs to CloudWatch Logs. **WARNING** This template
  enables log exports to CloudWatch Logs. You will be billed for the AWS
  resources used if you create a stack from this template.
Parameters:
  DBUsername:
    NoEcho: 'true'
    Description: Username for PostgreSQL database access
    Type: String
    MinLength: '1'
    MaxLength: '16'
    AllowedPattern: '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*'
    ConstraintDescription: must begin with a letter and contain only alphanumeric characters.
  DBPassword:
    NoEcho: 'true'
    Description: Password for PostgreSQL database access
    Type: String
    MinLength: '8'
    MaxLength: '41'
    AllowedPattern: '[a-zA-Z0-9]*'
    ConstraintDescription: must contain only alphanumeric characters.
Resources:
  RDSCluster:
    Type: 'AWS::RDS::DBCluster'
    Properties:
      MasterUsername: !Ref DBUsername
      MasterUserPassword: !Ref DBPassword
      DBClusterIdentifier: aurora-postgresql-cluster
      Engine: aurora-postgresql
      EngineVersion: '10.7'
      DBClusterParameterGroupName: default.aurora-postgresql10
      EnableCloudwatchLogsExports:
        - postgresql
  RDSDBInstance1:
    Type: 'AWS::RDS::DBInstance'
    Properties:
      DBInstanceIdentifier: aurora-postgresql-instance1
      Engine: aurora-postgresql
      DBClusterIdentifier: !Ref RDSCluster
      PubliclyAccessible: 'true'
      DBInstanceClass: db.r4.large
  RDSDBInstance2:
    Type: 'AWS::RDS::DBInstance'
    Properties:
      DBInstanceIdentifier: aurora-postgresql-instance2
      Engine: aurora-postgresql
      DBClusterIdentifier: !Ref RDSCluster
      PubliclyAccessible: 'true'
      DBInstanceClass: db.r4.large
```

Comment: Hi, @John I appreciate your answer as it has helped me a lot being a newbie in cloud formation.  Can direct me to the steps to create x number of reader instances along with one writer instance. Regards,

Comment: For other people who are new and confused like me. I created the first instance only thinking that adding another instance will add two writer instances however I was wrong. The first instance RDSDBInstance1 of this template creates a writer instance and the second instance RDSDBInstance2 creates a reader instance under same cluster.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer. However, another question rises now what if we want to create multiple writer instances under one cluster. Is it even possible? I will be researching on this and will post it here if found a solution.